# How to deal with java.net.SocketException: too many open files in dispatch/reboot?

Tags: sockets, scala, future

I have a method, that takes an url and returns a Promise[Stuff]:

```
def getStuff(url: String): Promise[Stuff] = Http(...).map(...)
```

and I call it on a big (~ 1300 items) list of strings:

```
Http.promise.all(urls.map(getStuff)).apply
```

Some of the promises complete properly, but about ~50 result in "java.net.SocketException: Too many open files". What am I doing wrong? Maybe I should use some other way to do this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an operating System limitation.

See http://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/Too+Many+Open+Files for example on linux

Comment: Well, that's sad. But how can I fix it in this particular case? Why does dispatch allocate more of those files than needed?

Comment: You must limit request with your own way. Do you use akka by example ?

Comment: No, no akka. Just plain dispatch, exactly as in my example.

Comment: Try with an executorcontext like implicit val executorService = Executors.newFixedThr eadPool(20) implicit val executorContext = ExecutionContext.from ExecutorService(execu torService)

Comment: I tried to do it like this: `val http = new Http(promiseExecutor = DaemonThreads(5), timeout = Duration.millis(120000))`. Didn't help. From output, I see that ~360 first promises report completed state (with that exception) almost immediately, then the rest proceed normally.

Comment: Doing all that stuff strictly sequentially works, but it very slow.

Comment: Right now, it seems that it is a bug/missing feature in the underlying AsyncHttpClient library. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: I am currently working on a library that adds (among other features) throttling on top of AsyncHttpClient, see https://github.com/hbf/tgv